# Как перебрать все элементы матрицы с помощью рекурсии (без повторения строк и столбцов)?

Tags: python-3.x

Пример варианта решения.

[image: Матрица 4х4]

[image: Выбран элемент а11]

[image: Итоговое решение]

Получено решение 1,4,17,4

--
Для реализации был написан следующий код

```
import numpy as np
matrix0 = np.array([[1, 10, 15, 5], [10, 2, 17, 7], [10, 2, 16, 4], [22, 4, 5, 8]])
saveArr=[]
mtr4=matrix0
for i4 in range(0, len(mtr4)):
    mtr3 = np.delete(mtr4, (i4), axis=0)
    mtr3 = np.delete(mtr3, (0), axis=1)
    
    for i3 in range(0, len(mtr3)):
        mtr2 = np.delete(mtr3, (i3), axis=0)
        mtr2 = np.delete(mtr2, (0), axis=1) 
        
        for i2 in range(0, len(mtr2)):
            mtr1 = np.delete(mtr2, (i2), axis=0)
            mtr1 = np.delete(mtr1, (0), axis=1)             
            saveArr.append(mtr4[i4,0])
            saveArr.append(mtr3[i3,0])
            saveArr.append(mtr2[i2,0])
            saveArr.append(int(mtr1))
```

Как реализовать подобное решение через рекурсию?
Исходная матрица может иметь большую размерность, но всегда квадратная.

Comment: Решение чего? Каково условие задачи?

Comment: Условие - перебрать все варианты решений. Пример одного из них приведен на картинках. При выборе элемента строка и столбец матрицы вычеркиваются. Для матрицы 4х4 существует (4!) решений

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно применить рекурсивный метод генерации перестановок списка чисел 0..n-1, и использовать элементы перестановки как индексы выборки. Удаление строк и т.п. - лишнее

```
def all_perms(elements):
    if len(elements) <=1:
        yield elements
    else:
        for perm in all_perms(elements[1:]):
            for i in range(len(elements)):
                yield perm[:i] + elements[0:1] + perm[i:]

l = [[1, 10, 15, 5], [10, 2, 17, 7], [10, 2, 16, 4], [22, 4, 5, 8]]

for p in all_perms(list(range(len(l)))):
    print([l[i][p[i]] for i in range(len(l))])

[1, 2, 16, 8]
[10, 10, 16, 8]
[10, 17, 10, 8]
[10, 17, 4, 22]
[1, 17, 2, 8]
[15, 10, 2, 8]
[15, 2, 10, 8]
[15, 2, 4, 22]
[1, 17, 4, 4]
[15, 10, 4, 4]
[15, 7, 10, 4]
[15, 7, 2, 22]
[1, 2, 4, 5]
[10, 10, 4, 5]
[10, 7, 10, 5]
[10, 7, 16, 22]
[1, 7, 2, 5]
[5, 10, 2, 5]
[5, 2, 10, 5]
[5, 2, 16, 22]
[1, 7, 16, 4]
[5, 10, 16, 4]
[5, 17, 10, 4]
[5, 17, 2, 22]
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! А то у меня с рекурсией совсем плохо